Twist coordinate frame when using `gz-sim-odometry-publisher-system`
I'm trying to understand the coordinate frame used when employing the gz-sim-odometry-publisher-system plugin in an .sdf file:
<plugin
  filename="gz-sim-odometry-publisher-system"
  name="gz::sim::systems::OdometryPublisher">
  <dimensions>3</dimensions>
  <odom_frame>world</odom_frame>
</plugin>

Specifically, I am uncertain whether the velocity within the gz.msgs.odometry message is expressed in the world frame (ENU).
I haven't found any relevant information in the plugin docs.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For anyone who also encounters this issue:
The velocity provided in the odometry message by the gz-sim-odometry-publisher-system plugin is given in the robot's body frame, not the world frame. This means the velocities are relative to the robot's local coordinate system.
If you need to convert these velocities to the world frame, you'll need to use the robot's orientation provided in the odometry message.
